# How to formulate the distribution and conduct a hypothesis test on the following situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

The situation is that we toss a coin N times. We note the outcome of each flip and we find the distribution of how many times the coin flipped the 'same way' n times in a row, for n = 1,2,3 etc (for N throws of ~ 1000 we wouldn't really go further than n = 12). i.e we count how many times the coin flips the same way (heads or tails) just once in a row (..T.. or ..H..), how many times it flips twice in a row (..TT.. or ..HH..), three times etc and then graph the frequency.

This distribution will be an exponential distribution, with a basic graph shown below (I have repeated the full experiement with N = 1000, 10 times and graphed the respective frequency for all 10 runs). This is fairly easy to think about as there should be roughly twice as many instances of (n-1) as n, because for every time we get the same outcome n-1 times in a row there is then a 50% chance of getting the same again.

[image]

My first question is, can someone actually analytically derive this distribution, rather than it currently just being my loose intuition?

Secondly, how would you then conduct a hypthesis test, for a sample of size N, in order to guage whether the set of produced heads and tails (or 0s and 1s, obviously doesn't really matter) were produced completely independantly and with a constant probability of 0.5?

It's obviously easy to check the final total number of heads and tails or 0s and 1s in order to hypothesis-test the probability value p (binomial distribution) but I need to figure out a way of hypothesis testing that the distribution of congruent outcomes, of degree n, fits the null hypothesis that all samples/coin flips were completely *independant* and probability remained constant at p.

Standard Chi square testing shouldn't work, unless I'm mistaken, as if we take the Xn to be the number of runs of degree n (for each value of n) then this is not a normally distributed variable.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is called a *runs test.*  Knuth has an extensive discussion in *The Art of Computer Programming* Vol. II.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition about the limit distribution of the longest consecutive streak of heads is correct.

There is a theorem, proved by Antónia Földes in "The limit distribution of the length of the longest head-run" (1979), that states:

> Suppose, $\tau(n)$ is the largest streak of heads among $n$ independent throws of an unbiased coin. Then $\frac{\tau(n)}{2^{n + 1}}$ converges in distribution to $Exp(1)$ (or equivalently $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\frac{\tau(n)}{2^{n + 1}} < x) = 1 - e^{-x}$ for all $x \in [0; +\infty)$)

Comment: ahhh interesting, that's really helpful, thanks!